# Geodetically correct point spacing accounting for change in elevation

Tags: arcgis-pro, vector-grid, measurements, geodetic

I am trying to create a grid of points at a specific spacing (30ft) for setting up a new orchard on fairly steep terrain. I have tried using "create fishnet" in ArcGIS pro.  This is giving me 30' spacing when viewing it on a 2D map, but when I measure it in my local scene it is showing more than 32' between points because of the change in elevation.

How can I create a grid of points at 30' spacing that accounts for changes in elevation?

In the image I attached, the left side shows the measurement on the 2d map (29.99') and the right side shows the measurement in my local scene with the points draped over an elevation model created from a UAV/photogrammetry (32.19').

[image]

Comment: Easily doable for single row, not sow much for next one. Moreover solution might not exist for 2nd point in second row.